# How can I use qtserialport without qtapplication

Tags: multithreading

The following are my codes about qtserialport:

```
[`// SerialPort.cpp

#include "GenControllerApi.h"
#include "QSerialThread.h"
#include "Global.h"
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtSerialPort>
#include <QEventloop>
#include <QMetaType>
#include <QObject>

SerialPortThread::SerialPortThread(QObject *parent):
     m_ringBuffer(1024)
{
    //set serialport
    m_serialPort.setPortName("COM1");
    m_serialPort.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud38400);
    m_serialPort.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    m_serialPort.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    m_serialPort.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    m_serialPort.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

    qRegisterMetaType<QSerialPort::SerialPortError>("QSerialPort::SerialPortError");
    // Connect the readyRead signal to a slot in this thread
    connect(&m_serialPort, &QSerialPort::readyRead, this, &SerialPortThread::onReadyRead); //

    // handle serial error signal
    connect(&m_serialPort, &QSerialPort::errorOccurred, this, [=](QSerialPort::SerialPortError error)
    {
        gLogger->Error(L"Serial port error occurred, error = %d.", error);
    });

    m_serialPort.moveToThread(this);
}

SerialPortThread::~SerialPortThread()
{
    quit();
    wait();
}

void SerialPortThread::run()
{
    CSnGenMsg msg;
    msg.Command = genCommQuery;
    msg.Data[0] = 0x01; //系统上电，建立通信问询
    if (!m_bIsPowerOn)
        openPort();
    else
    {
        bool success = m_serialPort.write(msg.GetBytes(), msg.GetLength());
        bool ifemit=m_serialPort.waitForReadyRead(1000);
        QByteArray data = m_serialPort.readAll();
    }


    QEventLoop loop;
    QTimer::singleShot(3000, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
    loop.exec();
}


bool SerialPortThread::openPort()
{
    
        if (m_serialPort.isOpen())
        {
            m_bIsPowerOn = true;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            bool success = m_serialPort.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
            if (success)
            {
                m_bIsPowerOn = true;
                gLogger->Trace(L"CGenerator::Open, Open serial port success");
            }
            else
            {
                m_bIsPowerOn = false;
                gLogger->Error(L"CGenerator::Open, Open serial port failed, maybe serial port is occupied");
                this->closePort();
            }
            return success;
        }
    
}

void SerialPortThread::closePort()
{
    // Close the serial port
    if (m_serialPort.isOpen()) {
        m_serialPort.close();
    }
}


void SerialPortThread::onReadyRead()
{
    // Emit the dataReceived signal with the received data
    QByteArray data = m_serialPort.readAll();
    gLogger->Trace(L"Serial port received, len = %d.", data.length());

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(m_mutex);
    m_ringBuffer.Write((unsigned char*)data.data(), data.length());
    locker.unlock();

    m_condition.notify_one();
}



#pragma once
// SerialPort.h

#include <QThread>
#include <QSerialPort>
#include <QTimer>
#include "RingBuffer.h"
#include <condition_variable>
#include <atomic>
#include <QObject>


class SerialPortThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    /**
    * @brief 构造函数
    * @param[in] notifyObserver 回调函数指针
    */
    SerialPortThread(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    ~SerialPortThread();

    bool openPort();

    void closePort();

    std::mutex m_mutex;

    std::condition_variable m_condition;

    CRingBuffer<unsigned char> m_ringBuffer;            // 接收消息缓冲区

    std::atomic<bool> m_bIsPowerOn = false;         // 是否开机

signals:
    void dataReceived(const QByteArray &data);

protected:
    void run() override;


private slots:
    void onReadyRead();

private:
    QSerialPort m_serialPort;

    QTimer m_timerReconnect;
};

and I start this thread by that :
CGenerator::CGenerator(IGenControllerNotifyEvent notifyObserver) :
    m_sendingThread(notifyObserver), m_ringBuffer(1024)
{
    gLogger->Trace(L"CGenerator, constructor began.");

    // 执行回调通知线程
    m_sendingThread.start();

    SerialPortThread *m_serialporthread = new SerialPortThread;
    m_serialporthread->start(); `
](https://stackoverflow.com)
```

My problem was that the readyread signal can not be triggered, and I am sure that seriport opened already,and it builed successfully.by the way , the other connect function is useless too, I am so confused about that.

I want to trigger the signal of readyread

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found it was caused by qt5.12.5 version, i edit the qt source code and rebuild my solution, it success!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).